# Chidren count return always 0 , can not reach correctly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently learning **Firebase** and start to writing a chat application

When the user **Login** and **Submit a Name** I update the values on **Firebase** and in other trying user directly must reach Main Page but users go Submit Page again and Again

[image: Firebase Users Child]

(**Submit Page** = Entering the user name)

Here is the submit code:

```
@IBAction func submitButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid;


        let profileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "defaultPhoto")!, 0.4);
        let profileImageRef = storageRef.child("ProfileImages/\(uid)/profileImage.jpg");


        profileImageRef.putData(profileData!, metadata: nil, completion: {
            (metadata , error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("error");
            }else
            {
                let username = self.nameTextField.text;
                let user : [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["uid" : uid!,
                    "username":username!];
                let childUpdates = ["Users/\(uid)/":user];
                databaseRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates);


                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Profiles");
                self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil);

            }
        })
```

When the user submits their name (i.e. Jordan , Username: Blabla) in first time, it goes to the Main Page. But in the other logins with same users, always goes to the **Submit Page**. I can not solve that

Then here is the Login Code:

```
func Login(email : String , password : String)
    {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email , password: password, completion:{
            (user , error) in
            if(error != nil)
            {
                print("Somethings wrong")
            }else
            {
                print("User login");

                let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid;

                print("UID == \(uid)");


                let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference();
                databaseRef.child("Users").child(uid!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
                    (snapshot) in


                    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
                    userDefaults.setValue(email, forKey: "emailKey");
                    userDefaults.setValue(password, forKey: "passwordKey");



                    if( snapshot.childrenCount == 0)
                    {
                        print("Children count = 0");
                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Setup");
                        self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil);

                    }else
                    {
                        print("Children count != 0");
                        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Profiles");
                        self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil);


                    }

                })




            }
        });
    }
```

Also I wonder why Users Child ' titles always with Optional like

```
Optional("Oa81jsagjassvZb14T1sSnS")
```

Maybe this transform to the string in database

Also i want to add console output

[image]

Comment: Don't post your code as images, write it as text instead.

Comment: You need to unwrap your optionals before using them for String interpolation.  Look at the value of `childUpdates` in the debugger before you pass it to your `updateChildValues` method and it should be obvious why it doesn't work.

Comment: Then it shows 0 before and after

Comment: thanks @dan for tell the where i wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved after the a bit trying .

// **WRONG**

```
  databaseRef.child("Users").child(uid!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
                (snapshot) in
                print("Children Count ->  \(snapshot.childrenCount) ");
     })
     // child update codes
     databaseRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates);
```

// **CORRECT**

```
if let testingOptional = uid
{
  databaseRef.child("Users").child(testingOptional).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
            (snapshot) in
            print("Children Count ->  \(snapshot.childrenCount) ");
 })
 // child update codes
 databaseRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates);

}
```

wrong input =  `Optional(0x12dsadue12315sdaj123)`

correct input = `0x12dsadue12315sdaj123`